# Python Bokeh: remove toolbar from chart

Tags: python, bokeh

*Note from maintainers: The specifics of this question concern the `bokeh.charts` API which is obsolete and was removed several years ago. In modern Bokeh, specify `toolbar_location`:*

```
p = figure(toolbar_location=None)
```

---

---

***OBSOLETE:***

I don't seem to be able to remove the toolbar from a bokeh Bar chart. Despite setting the *tools* argument to *None* (or *False* or *''*) I always end up with the bokeh logo and a grey line, e.g. with this code:

```
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show

# prepare some data
data = {"y": [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], "z": [1, 5, 12, 4, 2]}

# output to static HTML file
output_file("bar.html")

# create a new line chat with a title and axis labels
p = Bar(data, cat=['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'D1', 'D2'], title="Bar example",
                xlabel='categories', ylabel='values', width=400, height=400,
                tools=None)

# show the results
show(p)
```

However, when I try the same with a bokeh *plot*, it works perfectly fine and the toolbar is gone, e.g. with this code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("line.html")

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, toolbar_location=None)

# add a line renderer
p.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=2)

show(p)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you want to remove the logo and the toolbar you can do:

```
p.toolbar.logo = None
p.toolbar_location = None
```

Hope this resolves your problem

Comment: How can I remove the toolbar from a gridPlot, removing from suplots has no effect, removing gridplot is not possible: AttributeError: 'Column' object has no attribute 'toolbar'

Comment: toolbar_location=None, parameter of gridplot

Answer (score 5):

On any Bokeh plot object you can set:

```
p.toolbar_location = None
```

Comment: I tried that too (mentioned it within the parenthesis saying that _False_ and _''_ don't work either). But you're right, according to the guide it should work. Unfortunately it still gives me the logo and the horizontal line...

Comment: What version of Bokeh are you using?

Comment: `bokeh.__version__` gives me `0.9.2`

Comment: sorry for my late reply - I didn't receive an e-mail after you edited your answer and simply thought that everyone forgot about my question... your answer is right, and I can remove the logo with `p.logo`, as @Merqurio pointed out